# data-inline="true" not working in my example using query mobile.?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi can you please tell me how to  hide and show a div in query mobile.

May be i have two solution use hide and show function.

Or use toggle class ?
here is my fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/3LEdJ/2/
I need to show or hide on click of "openclosebutton" .This div

```html
  <div class="ui-grid-c">
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text"  class="textSearchvalue_h">     
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true" class="searchButtonClickText_h" >Search</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-c">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true" class="next_h">Next</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-d">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="previous_h">Previous</a>
       </div>
       <div class="ui-block-e">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="close_h">close</a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `data-inline` sets button width based on button text. Use http://www.lipsum.com/ to generate non-sense text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probem you have is the width of the text field. I suggest you to use a grid layout to achieve the desired effect:

```html
<div class="ui-grid-c">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text"  class="textSearchvalue_h">     
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true" class="searchButtonClickText_h" >Search</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-c">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true" class="next_h">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-d">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="previous_h">Previous</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

See the documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html).

Comment: Actually this div is scrolling .I need to fixed the that div .only scroll the below content(default data).Only scroll the this contends of this div having id(realTimeContents)